# List in flutter can't go to the full bottom

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have the following code in Flutter:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => 'Item $i');
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: PreferredSize(
      //   preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
      //   child: SafeArea(
      //     child: AppBar(
      //     ),
      //   ),
      // ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3e/a9/ba/3ea9ba9e84ab6808a394b6aa165c1673.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text(
                    items[index],
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

How can I achieve that items in list occupy the area at the bottom? I ask this especially because parent Container which has a background image already occupies this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this.

`top: true` will keep the safeArea at top. `bottom:false` will remove the safeArea part from bottom so that you could utilise the space.

```
 child: SafeArea(
      top: true,
      bottom: false,
```